# Makefile with linking different folders

Tags: c, linker, makefile

I have to build a makefile for a project that has the following folder structure:

1) all the headers are in /include

2) some .o compiled implementations are provided (without the .c) in /provided_objects

3) the source codes I create must be in /src

4) the .o files generated by my C codes must be in /built_objects

5) the executable is in the root

My original purpose is to replace some of the implementations in /provided_objects by my implementations, keeping in mind that my implementations can use the functions defined by the headers that I didnt implement.Theres already a default makefile that contains (among smaller details):

```
LD        = gcc
LDFLAGS   = -lm
OBJDIR    = provided_objects
OBJECTS = $(OBJDIR)/obj1.o    \    /$(OBJDIR)/obj2.o ...
MY_OBJECTS = 
quiet-command = $(if $(VERB),$1,$(if $(2),@echo $2 && $1, @$1))

all     : $(OBJDIR) $(PROG)

$(PROG) : $(OBJECTS) $(MY_OBJECTS)
    $(call quiet-command, $(LD) $^ -o $@, "  LD       $@" $(LDFLAGS))

$(OBJDIR):
    $(call quiet-command, mkdir -p $(OBJDIR),)
```

Im supposed to delete the entries that I implemented that are named in OBJECTS and reference them in MY_OBJECTS. My question is, how should I do this? Im not very experienced in makefiles and the links I found researching didnt address my constraints.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the `quit-command` thing? And, would be better to remove it, because it only make your makefile complicated without adding anything to your issue.

Comment: As I said, its a default makefile. It was given to me and Im supposed to change it. I have no idea what that does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you want correctly the `OBJECTS := ...` line in the makefile below should do what you want.

```
OBJDIR    = provided_objects
OBJECTS = $(OBJDIR)/obj1.o \
          $(OBJDIR)/obj2.o \
          $(OBJDIR)/obj3.o \
          $(OBJDIR)/obj4.o \
          $(OBJDIR)/obj5.o
MY_OBJDIR = built_objects
MY_OBJECTS = $(MY_OBJDIR)/obj2.o $(MY_OBJDIR)/obj4.o

$(info Before)
$(info OBJECTS: $(OBJECTS))
$(info MY_OBJECTS: $(MY_OBJECTS))

OBJECTS := $(filter-out $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(MY_OBJECTS))),$(OBJECTS))

$(info After)
$(info OBJECTS: $(OBJECTS))
$(info MY_OBJECTS: $(MY_OBJECTS))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this step by step :

1. **All the headers are in `/include`**

   ```make
    CPPFLAGS := -I /include # preprocessor flags
   ```
2. **Some `.o` compiled implementations are provided (without the `.c`) in `/provided_objects`**

   ```make
   PROVIDED_OBJ_DIR := /provided_objects
   PROVIDED_OBJ     := $(wildard $(PROVIDED_OBJ_DIR)/*.o)
   ```
3. **The source codes I create must be in `/src`**

   ```make
   SRC_DIR := /src
   SRC     := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
   ```
4. **The `.o` files generated by my C codes must be in `/built_objects`**

   ```make
   MY_OBJ_DIR := /built_objects
   MY_OBJ     := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(MY_OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
   ```
5. **The executable is in the root**

   ```make
   EXE := /executable
   ```
6. **Im supposed to delete the entries that I implemented that are named in `OBJECTS` and reference them in `MY_OBJECTS`.**

   ```make
   PROVIDED_OBJ := $(addprefix $(PROVIDED_OBJ_DIR)/,$(filter-out $(notdir $(MY_OBJ)), $(notdir $(PROVIDED_OBJ))))
   ```

   This line is a little bit long and complicated so let's review it too :

   The main goal is to filter out the object files you've reimplemented from the provided ones.
   Thus the function used is `$(filter-out files_to_remove, files_to_remove_from)`.

   ```make
   $(filter-out $(MY_OBJ), $(PROVIDED_OBJ))
   ```

   The problem is that files in `MY_OBJ` are prefixed with `/built_objects/` whereas files in `PROVIDED_OBJ` are prefixed with `/provided_objects/` so provided as is, nothing will be filtered out. We need to remove any path component from the names, so here comes the function `$(notdir files)`.

   ```make
   $(filter-out $(notdir $(MY_OBJ)), $(notdir $(PROVIDED_OBJ)))
   ```

   One final step : we need to re-add the right path else make won't find the files. Function `$(addprefix prefix, files)` to the rescue !

   ```make
   $(addprefix $(PROVIDED_OBJ_DIR)/,$(filter-out $(notdir $(MY_OBJ)), $(notdir $(PROVIDED_OBJ))))
   ```
7. **Finally, don't forget the right rules to compile all this ! Complete Makefile** :

   ```perl
   EXE                 :=  /executable

   SRC_DIR             :=  /src
   SRC                 :=  $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

   MY_OBJ_DIR          :=  /built_objects
   MY_OBJ              :=  $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(MY_OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

   PROVIDED_OBJ_DIR    :=  /provided_objects
   PROVIDED_OBJ        :=  $(wildcard $(PROVIDED_OBJ_DIR)/*.o)
   PROVIDED_OBJ        :=  $(addprefix $(PROVIDED_OBJ_DIR)/,$(filter-out $(notdir $(MY_OBJ)), $(notdir $(PROVIDED_OBJ))))

   LDFLAGS             :=  # -L flags
   LDLIBS              :=  -lm # -l flags

   CFLAGS              :=  -W -Wall
   CPPFLAGS            :=  -I /include

   .PHONY: all

   all:    $(EXE)

   $(EXE): $(MY_OBJ)
       $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(PROVIDED_OBJ) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

   $(MY_OBJ_DIR)/%.o:  $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
       @mkdir -p $(@D)
       $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
   ```